# how to get some filtered data from xml with the help of jquery?

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

```
 <Item id="419" rank="0.0000" date_added="2012-09-24T19:43:14" date_end="2012-10-15T19:43:14" uid="134333" price="  ,-" district="-1" district_text="Friend" cid="9" cid_text="Underholdning" img_height_thumb="433" />
  <Item id="418" rank="0.0000" date_added="2012-09-24T19:17:42" date_end="2012-10-15T19:17:42" uid="134332" price="  ,-" district="-1" district_text="Friend" cid="9" cid_text="Underholdning" img_height_thumb="254" />
  <Item id="405" rank="102.0000" date_added="2012-09-23T18:55:20" date_end="2012-10-14T18:55:20" uid="134331" price="  102,-" district="-1" district_text="Friend" cid="761" cid_text="Mote" img_height_thumb="280" />
```

This is sample xml data. And I am using this code to get xml.

I want to filter all data rank which is greater then 0. And I want to add filter only in this palce so my rest code won't change. So how could i filter items variable and get filter values in other variable. so the loop don't get effected. I can change the name of variables in for loop.

Please suggest me any idea for this.

```
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
        var items1 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Item");

    var items = $(items1).filter('Item').each(function () {
        var bRank = $(this).attr('rank');
        var tempRank = bRank.replace("0000", "").replace(".", "");
        if (tempRank > 0)
            return this;
    });

alert(items.length);
        alert(items1.length);
```

Answer of both alert is 3.

but answer should like this for first alert 1 and for second alert 3.

but i am getting same response each alert. please check and let me know your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wanted to use jQuery's [**.filter**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method with *function* argument instead:

```
var items = $(items1).filter(function () {
    var bRank = $(this).attr('rank');
    return parseInt(bRank, 10) > 0;
});
```

Here's [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zc9KU/) to play with. I obviously have to build the XML string by myself, and I got rid of `replace` code, as `parseInt` is much more suitable for, well, parsing an integer part from a string.

`.each` just invokes some code for each element of some collection, but it doesn't collect the results (as `.map` and `.filter` do) - in fact, it just returns the original collection. The only useful thing about `return` statement in `.each` function is that it can be used to break from an iteration (when `falsy` value is returned).